# Showing that $(b^*a)^+.(b^*a) = (b^*a)^*$

Tags: regular-expressions, kleene-star

I've been learning regular expressions as part of a class on automata and formal languages. I am still fine tuning and trying to figure out the algebra and the identities.

I am struggling with the regular expression
$$ (b^*a)^+.(b^*a) $$
It's supposed to come out as $$(b^*a)^*$$
I believe I have to use some identity between Kleene star and Kleene plus.

Comment: Please use MathJax environment (https://cs.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) instead of code environment, especially since the symbol $+$ have different significations in regular expressions depending if it is in exponent or not. $e + f$ means union between $e$ and $f$, $e^+f$ means Kleene plus of $e$ concatened to $f$.

Comment: … and I'm at a loss what the low-dot/fullstop is to mean.

Comment: @greybeard I have already seen some definitions where `.` is used for concatenation (Hopcroft, Motwani, Ullman, section 3.1.1 for example).

Comment: If `.` denotes concatenation then it's impossible for the given regular expression to be equivalent to `(b*a)*`: one regular expression matches both the empty word and `a` while the other regular expression matches neither.

Comment: The relevant identity is $r^+ = r^*r$. It seems you got your expressions mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

let A=(b* a)+ ,B=(b* a) and C=(b* a)*

we have to show that whether A.B=C

here . indicates the concatenation of strings

'+' is known as Kleene plus which means all kinds of non empty strings are accepted

A.B==>{(b*a),(b*a)(b*a),(b*a)(b*a)(b*a)…………}.(b*a)
==>{(b*a)(b*a),(b*a)(b*a)(b*a),(b*a)(b*a)(b*a)(b*a)}---->(1)

C on expansion gives

let e be epsilon

C={e, b*a ,(b*a)(b*a),(b*a)(b*a)(b*a),………………}--->(2)

clearly (2) is not same as (1)

hence A.B != C
==> (b* a). (b* a)= (b* a)* is wrong

Comment: (You need to "escape" multiplication signs to show up as "stars" - try `\*`.)

Comment: @greybeard,In TOC (theory of computation) we use * also known as asterisk as kleen symbol means set of all strings ,so in that aspect I believe i have given a brief explanation and not to be confused with multiplication

Comment: Great, but in *markdown* the multiplication sign is used to delimit text to be displayed in *standout mode*: Consult the *post editor* and markdown help and compare the text in the post editor and the preview.

Comment: @greybeard, To my knowledge my analysis and description is good and matchable to the perfect answer and I don't think there is usage of * to delimit text , I think dot symbol is used to delimit text

Answer (score 0):

It is the converse.

$$X^*X=X^+.$$

(This can be taken as a definition of the Kleene plus.)